# How to conditionally convert dates, numbers and factors from a list in R?

Tags: r, filtering, dt

I get the following vector in R from a Shiny DT dataframe as input$table_search_columns:

```
vec = ("2022-08-19 ... 2022-09-09","","","[\"CT101\",\"CT102\"]","","","8.59 ... 76.00","")
```

I'd like to apply this filtered conditions to my dataframe containing dates, numbers and factor columns.
Therefore, I'd like to end up with the following list:

```
[[1]]
2022-08-19 2022-09-09

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] "CT102" "CT104"

[[5]]
[1] NA

[[6]]
[1] NA

[[7]]
8.59 76.0

[[8]]
[1] NA
```

I tried to use the following code:

> ```
> filter_conditions <- lapply(myff, function(column) {
>   if (str_detect(column, "\\.\\.\\.")) {
>     vals <- strsplit(column, " ")
>     for (i in seq_along(vals)) {
>       current_vals <- vals[[i]][1]
>       is.convertible.to.number <- function(x) !is.na(as.numeric(x))
>       if (is.convertible.to.number(current_vals)) {
>         vals[[i]][1] = as.numeric(vals[[i]][1])
>         vals[[i]][3] = as.numeric(vals[[i]][3])
>         c(vals[[i]][1],vals[[i]][3])
>       } else {
>         vals[[i]][1] = as.Date(vals[[i]][1])
>         vals[[i]][3] = as.Date(vals[[i]][3])
>         c(vals[[i]][1],vals[[i]][3])
>       }
>     }
>   } else {
>     if (column == "") {
>       NA
>     } else {
>       vals <- strsplit(column, "\"")
>       index <- seq(from = 2, to = length(vals[[1]]), by = 2)
>       as.character(vals[[1]][index])
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

but I end up with NULL on numeric and dates filters:

```
    [[1]]
    NULL
    
    [[2]]
    [1] NA
    
    [[3]]
    [1] NA
    
    [[4]]
    [1] "CT102" "CT104"
    
    [[5]]
    [1] NA
    
    [[6]]
    [1] NA
    
    [[7]]
    NULL
    
    [[8]]
    [1] NA
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone can give me some assistance.

Comment: what's your desired output? could you explain what you want to do (not how you have tried to do it)?

Comment: Dear Christian, I'd like to achieve the first output I've shown in the text by starting from the following vector:                                                                                                                vec = ("2022-08-19 ... 2022-09-09","","","[\"CT101\",\"CT102\"]","","","8.59 ... 76.00","")

Comment: Thanks for your response. Kindly try the solution I posted and let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
lapply(stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(vec, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[-A-Z0-9]+"), 
       \(x) if(length(na.omit(z <- as.Date(x, "%Y-%m-%d")))) z else type.convert(x, as.is=TRUE))


[[1]]
[1] "2022-08-19" "2022-09-09"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] "CT101" "CT102"

[[5]]
[1] NA

[[6]]
[1] NA

[[7]]
[1]  8.59 76.00

[[8]]
[1] NA
```